# Postgresql: inserting some proper default values or NAs into table with maltyped values?

Tags: postgresql, csv, error-handling, plpgsql

I have a table with float columns. I want to insert a malformatted/maltyped CSV into it such that I cast all values to float and all malformatted values, firing an error, will get a zero value. In speudo code, I am looking for `iserror(cast(newValue as float),0)`.

**Small working example**

The CSV looks like this

```
Ex1,Ex2,Ex3
1,2,hhh
1.2,1.0,1.9
a,2,3
```

and the table creation with a clean copying

```
CREATE TABLE example
(
"Ex1" float,
"Ex2" float,
"Ex3" float
);

/*Copy with clean data*/
COPY example FROM '/tmp/test.csv' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',';
```

where the last command will fire errors because we cannot insert non-float values into the table.

[Error trapping](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) may help to solve my problem but I am uncertain how to use it with the insertion from CSV

```
[ <<label>> ]
[ DECLARE
    declarations ]
BEGIN
    statements
EXCEPTION
    WHEN condition [ OR condition ... ] THEN
        handler_statements
    [ WHEN condition [ OR condition ... ] THEN
          handler_statements
      ... ]
END;
```

### **Question**

> *How can I insert some proper default values or NAs into table with maltyped values?*

Comment: Create a function perhaps this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8833/type-conversion-with-default-fallback-value may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function may be useful also in other cases:

```
create or replace function to_float(text)
returns float language plpgsql as $$
begin
    return $1::float;
exception
    when invalid_text_representation then
        return 0::float;
end $$;
```

Unfortunately, you cannot use functions *inside* a COPY command. You need a buffer, i.e. a temporary table:

```
create temp table buffer (ex1 text, ex2 text, ex3 text);
copy buffer from '/tmp/test.csv' with csv header delimiter ',';

insert into example
select to_float(ex1), to_float(ex2), to_float(ex3)
from buffer;

drop table buffer;
```

Finally:

```
select *
from example;

 Ex1 | Ex2 | Ex3 
-----+-----+-----
   1 |   2 |   0
 1.2 |   1 | 1.9
   0 |   2 |   3
(3 rows)
```